# Magento 2 infrastructure

Tags: magento2

How will you setup infrastructure if you have to ask for eCommerce site which is on magento2 10,000 users hitting site simultaneously, some are on home page some are on checkout some are accessing admin ?

Comment: Highly Recommended that site should be hosted on AWS Cloud as they have built in feature https://shout.setfive.com/2013/04/02/aws-what-are-the-key-amazon-web-services-components/

Answer (score 0):

For high scalability, you can use AWS as your infrastructure.

For simplicity, you can use a dedicated server.

Both are relatively scalable, but AWS is more scalable than dedicated servers.